# Unit testing Scala

Tags: unit-testing, scala, tdd

I just recently started learning the Scala language and would like to do it in [TDD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development)-way. Could you share your experiences on the unit testing frameworks there are for Scala and the pros/cons of them.

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA for Scala development, so it would be nice to be able to run the tests with IDE-support.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Have you looked at [ScalaTest](http://www.artima.com/scalatest/) ?

I've not used it, but it comes from Bill Venners and co at Artima, and consequently I suspect it'll do the job. It doesn't appear to have IDE integration, however.

[This blog entry](http://www.theserverside.com/blogs/thread.tss?thread_id=48085) is a little old, but suggests that TestNG is the best option for testing Scala. TestNG will certainly have IDE integrations.

EDIT: I've just realised that I wrote this answer in 2009, and the world has moved on (!). I am currently using ScalaTest, the IDE integration works fine, and I can strongly recommend it. In particular the [matcher DSL](http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/using_matchers) works very nicely

Answer (score 20):

I'm the author of specs. If you're a Intellij user, I advise you to mix-in in the org.specs.runner.ScalaTest trait to your specification and run it as a ScalaTest suite.

If you have any issue with that, or anything else feel free to send a message to the [specs-users](http://groups.google.com/group/specs-users) mailing list.

Comment: Running Specs is now directly supported by the Scala plugin for IDEA 9 - the integration is seamless.

Answer (score 3):

You could also check out [Specs](http://code.google.com/p/specs/) it's fairly complete and IIRC is heavily used as part of Lift.